# Running Executables from Mapped Drive Shares

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, smb, mapped-drive

I have a directory which I’m sharing from my Macintosh. In it there are five executables.

I mapped the directory to `S:` on my Windows virtual machine (on VirtualBox). Four out of these five executables will run, but one gives me the message:

> S: \Software\SciTE4AutoIt3.exe
> The specified path does not exist.

Of course, the path exists. If I run via a UNC:

```
\\VBOXSVR\Shared\Software\SciTE4AutoIt3.exe
```

it’s OK.

So, there’s nothing wrong with the file, and it can be accessed from the network. Just not from the mapped drive.

I can make do with this, but what’s wrong with running it from the mapped drive?

Comment: Is the file actually named `Autoit` or `AutoLt`?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Oops - typo. Fixed. The names in real life are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably coming from the way that the executable is
programmed or linked. The message is then caused by some missing component
that is needed by the program. The `.exe` itself should be loaded
successfully into memory, but some referenced DLL or some other
dependency is not found, so the execution fails.

I can't point to where the problem is actually found inside the `.exe`.
It would happen for example if there was a reference to `..\..\file`,
since this would require a reference beyond the root of `S:`,
but your problem could be different.